# Calculating combinations of length k from a list of length n using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

I need to generate all the combinations with length `k` from a list of length `n`, and I must do it using recursion.

For Example:

```
INPUT:  choose_sets([1,2,3,4],3)
OUTPUT: [[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,3,4],[2,3,4]]
```

```
INPUT:  choose_sets([1,2,3,4],2)
OUTPUT: [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]
```

I'm stuck implementing this in code, so I would be happy for some help.
This is my code so far (I'm missing something just don't know what):

```
def choose_sets(lst,k):

    if k == len(lst):
        return lst
    if k == 0:
        return []
    if k > len(lst):
        return []

    sets=[]
    sub_lst=lst[:]
    sub_lst.remove(sub_lst[0])

    a= choose_sets(sub_lst,k-1)
    for i in a:
        i.append(lst[0])
    sets.append(a)

    b= choose_sets(sub_lst,k)
    sets.append(b)


    return sets
```

Comment: What language are you using and what specifically is wrong so far?

Comment: I'm using Python and the output is just not right and i don't really know how to make it right..

Comment: Yes Paul i've been trying for a few hours and can't get it right

Comment: Are you allowed to use iteration at all?  The most obvious algorithm will iterate through the whole set, but at each iteration it will recursively call itself on a smaller set.  (That's about as much hint as I can give without giving it away).

Comment: Hey Adrian,yes i'm allowed to use iteration as long as i have a recursion call in it. Can you please elaborate on the solution? I know that it needs to call itself on a smaller set but i cant get the implementation right..

Comment: `list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4], r=3))` -> `[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 3, 4), (2, 3, 4)]`

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't provide a debugging service - if the question was meant to be specifically about the code attempt, then it needed to have a clearly identified problem, a question clearly asked specifically about that problem, and a [mre] that isolated the problematic part from the overall algorithm. It's much more natural to interpret the question as simply being about the task; having to write the code in a specific way (e.g. "using recursion") doesn't make it a different question. I've closed this as a duplicate; the canonical fortunately already has an answer using recursion.

Answer (score 7):

You can get solution from [Generator for permutations, combinations, selections of a sequence (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/190465-generator-for-permutations-combinations-selections/)

```
def xuniqueCombinations(items, n):
    if n==0: yield []
    else:
        for i in xrange(len(items)):
            for cc in xuniqueCombinations(items[i+1:],n-1):
                yield [items[i]]+cc



>>> def xuniqueCombinations(items, n):
...     if n==0: yield []
...     else:
...         for i in xrange(len(items)):
...             for cc in xuniqueCombinations(items[i+1:],n-1):
...                 yield [items[i]]+cc
... 
>>> for x in xuniqueCombinations( [1,2,3,4],2):
...     print x
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[2, 3]
[2, 4]
[3, 4]
```

**Edited 4 year later** *(7/12/2015)*

To run it on Python3 just change `xrange` to `range`, [Python3's range is Python2's xrange.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15015199). Thanks [@ederollora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2317111/ederollora) to notice me.

Comment: Am getting a "object of type 'int' has no len()" when I try the repl one.

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson, be sure first parm is enumerable.

Comment: Thank you, this saved my bacon!

Comment: This works for python27, not python35, probably xrange cannot be used. Just change it to range. Checked that works in python35.

Comment: @ederollora, yes, just change `xrange` to `range`, [Python3's range is Python2's xrange.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15015199)

Answer (score 0):

Give a look to this solution:

```
def choose_sets(mylist,length):
    mylen = len(mylist)

    if length == mylen:
        return [mylist]
    if length == 1:
        return [[i] for i in mylist]
    if length > mylen:
        return []

    ToRet = []
    for k in xrange(mylen): 
        if mylen - k + 1> length :
            for j in choose_sets(mylist[k+1:],length-1):
                New = [mylist[k]]
                New.extend(j)
                ToRet.append(New)
    return ToRet

print choose_sets([1,2,3,4,5],3)
```

there are more elegant ways, but this should be ok as homework...

Answer (score 0):

This is in Java, and I can't guarantee it works 100% properly, but based on quick prototyping seemed to work ok. Hope this helps a bit in any case.

```
public void choose_sets(int values[], int count) {
    int perm[] = new int[count];
    choose_sets(values, 0, perm, 0, count);
}

public void choose_sets(int[] values, int valuesIdx, int[] perm,
                        int permIdx, int count) {
    if (permIdx == count) {
        // At this point perm -array contains single permutation
        // of length ´count´.
    } else {
        for (int i = valuesIdx; i < values.length; ++i) {
            perm[permIdx] = values[i];
            choose_sets(values, i + 1, perm, permIdx + 1, count);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just a few minor things. The algorithm is basically correct, but

```
if k == len(lst):
    return lst
```

This has the wrong type. The return type is not a list of *thing*, but a list of (list of *thing*), so that should be

```
if k == len(lst):
    return [lst]
```

Next,

```
if k == 0:
    return []
```

Every list has exactly one nonempty sublist, the empty list, so that ought to be

```
if k == 0:
    return [[]]
```

For the rest,

```
if k > len(lst):
    return []
```

is completely correct.

```
sets=[]
sub_lst=lst[:]
sub_lst.remove(sub_lst[0])
```

That is correct but could be put more succinctly as

```
sub_lst = lst[1:]
```

Now, another type mix-up:

```
a= choose_sets(sub_lst,k-1)
for i in a:
    i.append(lst[0])
sets.append(a)
```

That `sets.append(a)` puts `a` into one slot of `sets`, you want to concatenate the two lists, `sets = sets + a`. And if you would like the combinations in the order in which elements appear in the list, instead of `i.append(lst[0])`, you should append `[lst[0]] + i` to `sets` in the loop, but that's a matter of inclination.

```
b= choose_sets(sub_lst,k)
sets.append(b)
```

Again, do not append, but concatenate here,

```
sets = sets + b
```

Comment: If you use `for i in a: i.append(lst[0])`, then I have no idea, because that works correctly here. If you're using `for i in a: i = [lst[0]] + i`, then it's because I always forget Python's scoping rules. I had `for i in a: sets.append([lst[0]]+i)` originally, and that works too, but assigning to `i` in the loop doesn't change the element in `a`.

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to use the following recursion:

f(k,n) = append_to_each( f(k-1,n-1), n) | f(k,n-1)

```
def combinations(lst,k):
    n = len(lst)
    if n == k:
        return [set(lst)]
    if k == 1:
        return [set([lst[i]]) for i in range(n)]
    v1 = combinations(lst[:-1], k-1)
    v1new = [ i.add(lst[n-1]) for i in v1]
    v2 = combinations(lst[:-1], k)
    return v1+v2
```